# Android Allow some users to download my app free from PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

I have a paid app in PlayStore. I want to let some users download my app for free. There is no in-app purchase feature in my app. One thing that I can do that by emailing them the apk file and then they download on their phones but it involves some risk of misuse. So my question is is there option available in PlayStore which can let me do this?
OK, in APK section of the Google Play Console, I saw two options i.e Beta Testing and Alpha Testing. I decided to upload a beta apk and then allow a Google group to become tester and download my app. When the user goes to the link provided by the Beta Testing, it asks user to configure my Google Wallet account. Is it necessary to have a payment account configured to be able to test beta app?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that by adding their gmail ids. Click on **Settings** in Google console and then you will see a field "**Gmail accounts with testing access**". Add their gmail ids there.

Then these users will be dummy billed which means money wont be deducted from their account.

Comment: I followed the steps and found the following options there:
Create & edit draft apps
 >Edit store listing, pricing & distribution
 >Manage Production APKs
 >Manage Alpha & Beta APKs
 >Manage Alpha & Beta users
 >View financial reports
 >Reply to reviews
 >Edit games
 >Publish games
I cannot see the option you mentioned.

Comment: Also I can see two tabs i.e Beta Testing, Alpha Testing. Can they meet my requirement?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look if you can help.

Comment: As it is a paid app, so a part of testing will also including billing for the app. But for alpha and beta testers, the biling will be dummy billing ie the money wont be deducted from their account. So, dont worry about that. For the case I mentioned, check the extreme left of page in Goggle Console. You will find settings option. Click on that and you will see the field to mention emails.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Beta-testing and staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)